# How to add Primeng dropdown to table header and based on dropdown selection how to show the selected value in primeng Table

Tags: primeng, primeng-dropdowns, primeng-table

How  to show primeng dropdown inside p-table header and based on the selection of  dropdown selected value it should filter and  displays the value in table column.
Anyone help on my queries.

Answer (score 1):

See this [Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tabledoc-demo-eyhllm) Write your logic for change the table detail inside the "**dropDownUpdate()**" function.